# Mongo aggregation, accessing a portion of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document like this

```
{
  '_id': .bson.
  'key': [ 'word1', 'word2', { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' } ] 
},
```

How do I use the mongo aggregation framework to make the document look like this:

```
{
  '_id': .bson.
  'key2': 'value2'
},
```

Thank you in advance!

-daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$key"}, 
                          {$group : {
                                      "_id" : "$_id", 
                                      "key2": {$max: "$key.key2"}
                                    }
                          }])
```

Replace $max with $last if you are sure key.key2 is always present in the ***last*** element of key array.

Comment: Well, I'm stunned.  I had never though that $max could be used in that manner!